# Django Queryset - Sort alphabetical then move specific entries to top

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

## Edit (Background info)

I've created a custom UserModelChoiceField class that takes a QuerySet of users and populates a select field with their full names:

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "{} ({})".format(obj.get_full_name(), obj.username)
```

I'm now attempting to use this class like:

```
calibrated_by_internal = UserModelChoiceField(
                                              queryset=total_qs,
                                              required=False,
                                              widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"})
                                              )
```

.

## Original Question

I'm trying to create a custom sorted QuerySet that will allow me to put a User ModelChoice select field on a form that is sorted alphabetically, but 3 members of a particular permissions group are put at the top.

For example:

Members of the group:
Charlie, Alan, Brian

Not members of the group:
Ben, Chris, Alicia... etc.

Required QuerySet / Select Field ordering:
Alan, Brian, Charlie, Alicia, Ben, Chris... etc.

Given that I'm using Django 1.11 I thought I'd try the new .union ORM function:

```
group_members = User.objects.filter(groups__name="AddEditCalibrations").order_by("first_name", "last_name")
everyone_else = User.objects.exclude(username__in="group_members").order_by("first_name", "last_name")
total_qs = group_members.union(everyone_else)
```

Which just raises the error:

```
DATABASE ERROR - ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements
```

It seems to work OK without the 2 ORDER_BYs, but then the list isn't sorted alphabetically and the members of that group that need to be at the top of the select (first in the QS) are just mixed in with everyone else.

So I tried the even simpler:

```
total_qs = User.objects.order_by(groups__name="AddEditCalibrations", "first_name", "last_name")
```

Which raises error:

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

## Edit

Following rajkris' suggestion of using itertools I tried:

```
total_list = list(chain(group_members, everyone_else))
```

Given that I need a QS to populate the select field I then tried to convert it back to a QS with:

```
total_qs = User.objects.filter(username__in=total_list)
```

But this only got me an unsorted list with all users mixed together without any ordering.

Comment: What is the sort(User.objects.sort()) you are using? Is it a manageer method you defined?

Comment: Apologies, a typo from copying the code over from memory (a hangup from a different language I used to use)

I've update the question, the error message raised is still the same.

Comment: order_by will not accept keword args. I think you cannot use order_by for your situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot order by a condition with that syntax. You could order by `groups__name` but that's not what you want. Instead you need to translate it into another field by which you can order—let's call it the `weight`; `groups__name="AddEditCalibrations"` should get a `weight` of `0` and every other should get a weight of `1`.

You can try this:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Value

group_members = User.objects.filter(groups__name="AddEditCalibrations").annotate(weight=Value(0, IntegerField()))
everyone_else = User.objects.exclude(groups__name="AddEditCalibrations").annotate(weight=Value(1, IntegerField()))
total_qs = group_members.union(everyone_else).order_by("weight", "first_name", "last_name")
```

If your `union` still doesn't work as expected, you might need `all=True`.

Alternatively, in one go:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When

total_qs = User.objects.annotate(weight=Case(
    When(groups__name="AddEditCalibrations", then=Value(0)),
    default=Value(1),
    output_field=IntegerField()
)).order_by("weight", "first_name", "last_name")
```

Comment: @TimB Any luck?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back round to this, something urgent came up at work that took me off of dev for a few weeks.

Your edited second solution works perfectly and I'm pushing it to production this afternoon.  Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually scrap that, it seems that anyone in the AddEditCalibrations group appears in the qs twice, once at the top then again further down.  This means that when one of them is chosen we get a MultipleObjectsReturned error: get() returned more than one User -- it returned 2!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try out chain from itertools to convert it into a list:

```
from itertools import chain
result_list = list(chain(group_members, everyone_else))
```

AND maybe we can use something like this for obtaining the queryset.

```
pk_list = [each.id for each in result_list]
ordering = 'FIELD(`id`, %s)' % ','.join(str(id) for id in pk_list)
queryset = User.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).extra(
       select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this puts the whole QS in alphabetical order, including the two users who I need to be at the top (members of the AddEditCalibrations group).  

What I'd like is the users of that group sorted alphabetically, then below them all other users separately sorted alphabetically.  Sorry if I wasn't clear enough!

Comment: I dont think we could use union in this case then. Maybe use itertool chain for appending both the ordered queryset. Updated the answer

Comment: I tried as you suggested and got a sorted list, but then when I converted it back to a QS it became unsorted again!  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I think you dont need a qs to populate a select field,  a list should be sufficient enough to iterated over to populate the select field. Please confirm if the resulting list is sorted as you expected.

Comment: I tried, and got a AttributeError - 'list' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you tried? A list does not have attribute all(). If you want to iterate over the list , do: for user in result_list: #do something

Comment: I've added more info the top of the question showing where I need the "total_qs" queryset.

Comment: Last couple of lines of traceback:
File "C:\[bla bla]\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" line 966 in get_prep_value
return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Updated the answer  A silly mistake. Please check. I changed in filter: pk__in=[pk_list] to pk__in=pk_list. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this?

```
group_members = User.objects.order_by("first_name", "last_name")
sorted_group_members = sorted(group_members.all(), reverse=True, key = lambda a: a.some_function_returning_the_user_group_of_each_user())
```